# Error when installing RVM as jenkins user

Tags: ruby, jenkins, docker

I am trying to setup a docker container that has jenkins and rvm installed, but everytime i try and install rvm as the `jenkins` user i get the following error

```
GPG signature verification failed for '/var/jenkins_home/.rvm/archives/rvm-1.27.0.tgz' - 'https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.27.0/1.27.0.tar.gz.asc'! try downloading the signatures:
```

So far my Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM jenkins
USER root
# Install some dependencies
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y -q install curl patch gawk g++ gcc make libc6-dev patch libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 autoconf libgmp-dev libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison pkg-config libffi-dev
USER jenkins
# Install rvm
RUN gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3
RUN \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Output

```
Step 6 : RUN \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
---> Running in 45b40000a9f1
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.27.0.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.27.0/1.27.0.tar.gz.asc
gpg: directory `/var/jenkins_home/.gnupg' created
gpg: new configuration file `/var/jenkins_home/.gnupg/gpg.conf' created
gpg: WARNING: options in `/var/jenkins_home/.gnupg/gpg.conf' are not yet active during this run
gpg: keyring `/var/jenkins_home/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: Signature made Tue 29 Mar 2016 01:49:47 PM UTC using RSA key ID BF04FF17
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
```

Any ideas to what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to do the following (as the jenkins user, of course:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
```

...which is specified at https://rvm.io/rvm/install.